# Fastest Aggregate function when you have series of duplicate values

Tags: sql-server, performance, query

Frequently, I'll need to crunch down a table into a series of aggregates.

And frequently, it will look like this.

```
John, Smith, Houston, Texas, Order 55, Balloon, 99 dollars
John, Smith, Houston, Texas, Order 55, Bicycle, 400 dollars
```

In other words, there's the "key column" to group by (order ID in this case).

There's then columns that should be "summed" or "counted" or properly aggregated.

Then there's a bunch of columns that are just duplicated values. This happens a lot and is not necessarily a normalization problem (or you're querying a database like this anyway that you don't admin).

Seems like there's a few choices here. Max(blah), max(ha) max(whatver).

Or min(every column). Obviously since they're all the same, it'll return it.

There's also "group by" each of those duplicate columns. Naturally, this can provide different results depending on your assumptions/ certainty that the columns will be duplicated.

Then there's also, in MySQL only (not MS or Oracle) -- putting nada, and it'll just take the first row found.

Which is typically the fastest? I suppose the best way is to test it. Just wondering though.

Comment: It will likely depend on your indexing strategy. Can you provide that?

Comment: Uncertain on the table being queried --- let's say only Order Id is indexed

Answer (score 2):

Given the current design, I don't know if there will be one approach that is noticeably more efficient than any other. You may be able to minimize the pain by creating an index on just OrderID and Price, making it relatively efficient to group by OrderID and SUM(Price), but then to get back the repeated information like name and address, you're still going to have to go back to the whole table. Perhaps an indexed view on the duplicates (OrderID + demographics), but really you should only be storing that information once in the first place. Then there's the question of what to do with values that *can't* be aggregated and also are absolutely not duplicated, like `Balloon` and `Bicycle`. When you have these two rows for the same order, you can collapse the name and address, and SUM() the price, but what do you expect to show for the product?

Why isn't your design more like a traditional store schema?

- Customers

  - CustomerID (PK)
  - Name (once!)
  - e-mail
  - PasswordHash
  - etc. etc.
- Addresses (so customers can have more than one address)

  - AddressID (PK)
  - CustomerID (FK)
  - Street
  - City
  - Region
  - Postcode
  - etc. etc.
- Products

  - ProductID (PK)
  - Description
  - Price
  - etc. etc.
- Orders

  - OrderID (PK)
  - CustomerID (FK)
  - Date
  - etc. etc.
- OrderDetails

  - OrderID (FK)
  - ProductID (FK)
  - Quantity
  - etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I seem to face this situation often -- as the query Person in this case, not the database developer. Frequently, many databases just have "mindless software" writing down transaction details, with little thought towards normalization (or in some cases it may be impossible). So, the question is how to most efficiently query these tables (assuming the source cannot be changed) -- not in optimizing the existing table design, whether that's even possible or a separate positive idea.

Comment: For bicycle, balloon -- simply depends on if I care about that data. A group_concat, xml, listagg, or whatever can be used depending on SQL flavor. This is probably common problem as at heart, there are usually many product combinations on an order. However a 'contact' or 'refund' (sometimes) or "issue" -- not to mention payment fees -- and much else --- is often associated with an 'entire order' - and doesn't have the granularity of product. But that is more data modeling problems. But yes I'd probably do a string_agg --- probably take the top 3 products at most (reduce combinations)

Comment: Not sure much anyone answered the question -- what is the fastest aggregation when you "don't care" about the result? Duplicate values, I mean.

Comment: @user45867 You want us to tell you what will be the fastest aggregation for all these different potential use cases, on your hardware, against your data, with indexes we don't see and usage patterns we can't possibly know? **You** can (and *should*) be testing that yourself. But if you're going to write data to a table in a form that makes it inefficient to query, again, like I said in my answer, you're not going to find much difference in the approaches you suggest when you have to, by definition, read the entire table anyway.

Comment: You forgot the part where you're not in control of the database design you're querying. And actually there are significant cases where this comes up without normalization violations either. Say you have 'tickets - current properties'  and 'tickets - events' -- you might join those tables at some point for various reasons. And again, you may have a 'collapse' situation with duplicate values. Why not collapse the (many) of the one-to-many table first? Then you'd have to maintain duplicate (possibly complex) join logic in two places. Yeah, without a lot of reporting I suppose it appears alien

Comment: @user45867 I didn’t forget that part (my answer actually leads with that) and none of this is alien to me. I’ve been working with SQL Server for over two decades, and in an overwhelming majority of all scenarios, good performance is dependent on good design. If you’re stuck with bad design, that’s not a criticism, just a symptom...